# How to count the occurences of a substring (first three indexes) using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I am trying to count how many phone numbers within my csv file start with the numbers "123", "456", and "789", in three different columns.

I initially approached this with RegEx:

```
num_list = ['123', '456', '789']

rgx = '({})'.format('|'.join(num_list))

df['Series1'].str.lower().str.extractall(rgx).iloc[:, 0].value_counts()
df['Series2'].str.lower().str.extractall(rgx).iloc[:, 0].value_counts()
df['Series3'].str.lower().str.extractall(rgx).iloc[:, 0].value_counts()
```

The problem with this approach, however, is that I feel it looks for those numbers regardless of its position within the string. I'm only interested in counting the ones that START with any of those substrings.

Comment: how about `str.startswith(num_list)` or with `^` in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.startswith( tuple(num_list) )`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': [
        '123-000-000',
        '456-000-000',
        '789-000-000',
        '000-123-000',
        '000-456-000',
        '000-789-000',  
        '000-000-123',
        '000-000-456',
        '000-000-789',        
    ], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#print(df)

num_list = ['123', '456', '789']

selected = df[ df['A'].str.startswith( tuple(num_list) ) ]
print(selected)

counts = df['A'].str.startswith( tuple(num_list) ).value_counts()
print('count True :', counts[True])
print('count False:', counts[False])
```

Result

```
             A
0  123-000-000
1  456-000-000
2  789-000-000

count True : 3
count False: 6
```

---

If you want to use regex then you should add `^`

to have `^(123|456|789)`

```
rgx = '^({})'.format('|'.join(num_list))
```

or `(^123|^456|^789)`

```
rgx = '(^{})'.format('|^'.join(num_list
```